# How to get started writing device driver for Linux?

Tags: usb, linux-device-driver

I have a USB 3.0 PCI card for a laptop.  There are drivers up to Windows 7 only.  Device I have https://www.startech.com/Cards-Adapters/USB-3.0/Cards/2-Port-ExpressCard-SuperSpeed-USB-3-Card-Adapter~ECUSB3S22#dnlds

I have older laptops running Ubuntu 16.  I want to create a Linux driver for this card.

Some hints on who wrote the software.  When installing the software, a different company is displayed.  This is the company https://www.renesas.com/en-us/products/software-tools/software-os-middleware-driver.html

I am wondering if I can leverage some of the Windows 7 Driver files and the Renesas specifications to get started.

I do not have a good reference on Linux device drivers.  Any guidance on where I can start?  My only experience is some C/C++ long time ago on MS Windows and web based business applications with Java.

Comment: Writing USB 3.0 driver for Linux is quite complex task. It must be written is kernel-space not user-space - so you need to know how the kernel works. Of course additionally you need to know almost everything about USB protocols. A lot of docs to read - thousand of sides of specs. It is not a project for one or two weekends. For one person without experience in kernel-space programming and without any hardware usb protocol analyser it may take a lot of months or even years to write it.

Answer (score 6):

first read about the *Linux Device Driver Model*

- **https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/tab/linux-device-driver-model**
- https://static.lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch14.pdf
- http://www.staroceans.org/kernel-and-driver/The%20Linux%20Kernel%20Driver%20Model.pdf

you have to write a kernel module / driver that registers the card as a *root hub*

if you run `lsusb` on linux the USB host ports are the root hubs

also run `lspci -v` to get the PCI devices, your kernel module has to include link to the kernel driver `pcieport` and *Extensible Host Controller Interface* `xhci_hcd` ( Linux Device Driver Model )

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=112069

an example with source code for this is in

- https://github.com/geoffreytran/AX88179_178A
- https://github.com/geoffreytran/AX88179_178A/blob/master/ax88179_178a.c

USB hubs in general are in https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/usb/core/hub.c

key components of USB kernel modules are URBs ( USB Request Blocks )

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure a good starting point if you haven't already is look at Linux/Unix kernal reading. That way you have a solid understanding of how the kernel works & then read specs on USB protocol. I saw a youtube video on this guy who used a signal or spectral analyzer and decoded what the signals showed on the screen and printed 3 packets of data exchanged from a USB keyboard.

If you start there I'm sure you're on your way writing a device driver, but this is a challenging task...very important you know your basics on the protocol, kernel, and I believe pinouts and frequencies (full vs half speed).